# Weblogic 12.1.3.0.0 - Ehcache JMS Replication - InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId

Tags: java, ehcache, weblogic12c

I have Spring based application with Ehcache JMS Replication. I need to deploy this application to Weblogic 12, however there is following error that fails deployment:

```
javax.jms.InvalidSelectorException: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException:
Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500
```

---

**What is wrong?**

*weblogic-application.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.3/weblogic-application.xsd">

    <!--Configure the FilteringClassLoader to specify a certain package is loaded from an application-->

    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <!--<wls:package-name>javax.validation.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</wls:package-name>-->
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.spi.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.criteria.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.metamodel.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>net.sf.ehcache.*</wls:package-name>
        <!--<wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>-->
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
        <!--ftp-->
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.net.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>com.thoughtworks.xstream.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.google.*</wls:package-name>

    </wls:prefer-application-packages>

</wls:weblogic-application>
```

*Maven dependencies:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-jmsreplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Full Stack Trace:**

```
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheCachingAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0' while setting bean property 'pointcut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0' while setting bean property 'cacheAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'serviceCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceCacheManager' defined in class path resource [service-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Exception while creating JMS connections: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0' while setting bean property 'cacheAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'serviceCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceCacheManager' defined in class path resource [service-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Exception while creating JMS connections: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'serviceCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceCacheManager' defined in class path resource [service-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Exception while creating JMS connections: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceCacheManager' defined in class path resource [service-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Exception while creating JMS connections: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Exception while creating JMS connections: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jms.JMSCacheManagerPeerProvider.init(JMSCacheManagerPeerProvider.java:193)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:447)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:377)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:259)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1037)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.jms.InvalidSelectorException: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.convertToJMSExceptionAndThrow(DispatcherAdapter.java:110)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSync(DispatcherAdapter.java:45)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.consumerCreate(JMSSession.java:3048)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.setupConsumer(JMSSession.java:2806)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createConsumer(JMSSession.java:2748)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.jms.InvalidSelectorException: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.Request.handleThrowable(Request.java:87)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.Request.getResult(Request.java:52)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:1135)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.syncRequest(DispatcherImpl.java:201)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchSync(DispatcherImpl.java:236)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.jms.InvalidSelectorException: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.convertToJMSExceptionAndThrow(DispatcherAdapter.java:110)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSync(DispatcherAdapter.java:45)
    at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEConsumer.<init>(FEConsumer.java:296)
    at weblogic.jms.frontend.FESession$2.run(FESession.java:1078)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.jms.InvalidSelectorException: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.Request.handleThrowable(Request.java:87)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.Request.getResult(Request.java:52)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:1135)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.syncRequest(DispatcherImpl.java:201)
    at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchSync(DispatcherImpl.java:236)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.jms.InvalidSelectorException: weblogic.messaging.kernel.InvalidExpressionException: Expression : "cacheManagerUniqueId <> 600767500"
    at weblogic.jms.backend.BEQueueImpl.createFilterExpression(BEQueueImpl.java:161)
    at weblogic.jms.backend.BEQueueImpl.createConsumer(BEQueueImpl.java:188)
    at weblogic.jms.backend.BESessionImpl.createBEConsumer(BESessionImpl.java:469)
    at weblogic.jms.backend.BESessionImpl.createConsumer(BESessionImpl.java:479)
    at weblogic.jms.backend.BESessionImpl.invoke(BESessionImpl.java:297)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: do you have any progress on this?

Comment: This works on the lower version of weblogic? Like 10? With the Java6?

Comment: It doesn't work with weblogic 10 due to other dependencies I have in the project

Answer (score 0):

There is similar question without solve:

- https://community.oracle.com/thread/938782

The problem with expressions, which are used to route messages in JMS of ehcache.
Ehcache is open source, you can see example code (I got from [github](https://github.com/thierrymonney/ehcache-jmsreplication/blob/71e50ea77b1bf4725dc68b4ea820bdd0461d5a92/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/distribution/jms/JMSCacheManagerPeerProvider.java#L194), but of course you can get ehcache source from their site, if you'd like):

```
String messageSelector = CACHE_MANAGER_UID + " <> " + localCacheManagerUid(cacheManager);
```

Despite of Weblogic, which are not open source. So I suppose you to debug code and see what happens inside

```
weblogic.jms.backend.BEQueueImpl.createFilterExpression
```

because it obviously that it doesn't support this grammar.

Possible reason could be conflict with [antlr.jar](http://www.antlr.org/) library between your application and weblogic. In that case you should try to configure preferred packages in your configuration.

Comment: I also think it is somehow related to the antlr library conflicts but I already tried to include antlr in <wls:prefer-application-packages> as well as exclude it from there (rely on weblogic dependency). In both cases it doesn't work properly, however this is the main suspect...